# Mapping one table to another based on a deciding attribute Hibernate/JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have two different tables with the same boolean attribute named hasValue.I am trying to establish a many to one mapping using hibernate/JPA from a third table to either of the two based on the value of hasValue. How would I write this conditional using Hibernate? I am pretty new to Hibernate so any help would be appreciated. I have provided a ERD explaining the relationship in the link below.

**ER Diagram:**
[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: Not i'm not sure but i don't think it happens on same way you think for other. I tried same thing using generics or other way but at the end it I stopped at the point (which i know arise), which child entity or table it relate when perform any DDL operation(Because Generic not able to map entity class). @Target and @ManyToOne(targetEntity) both not allow multiple value. Question : if you fire any query to insert MySQL then what is it?

Comment: Have a look at Hibernate's `@Any`